# How to make sure quartz.properties is being used?

Tags: java, threadpool, quartz-scheduler

I set following properties in my quartz.properties file:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 60
org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount = 60
```

, however, for some reason, apparently it doesn't take effect. because when I start my application, the log shows that it still uses 1 thread in the pool:

```
[main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor 
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl 
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.1.1 created. 
[main] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
[main] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.1) 'QuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED' Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally. NOT STARTED. Currently in standby mode. Number of jobs executed: 0   
Using **thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.**
```

I know, the quartz.properties needs to be at class path to be found. and I just did it.
any other reason why this file is not detected? or it is detected but number of threads is not set correctly?

Thanks

Comment: what is the location of your quartz.properties i am using quartz 2.0 and get in log  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 20 threads.
Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

[Feb 5 18:42:40 2013] [INFO ] [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory]: Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'

Comment: I tried different locations, currently I changed the quartz.properties which locates in quartz-2.1.1 folder itself. I mean, I extracted the jar file(after I got disappointed enough :) and I changed the quartz.properties that already existed in quartz-2.1.1\org\quartz folder. however the log shows: [main] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance. wish I can make my console like yours (20 threads)

Comment: Oh now I think my properties file is not read at all, because the name of scheduler in the file is DefaultQuartzScheduler however QuartzScheduler is printed in console.

Comment: oops, I found the problem, actually the code was overriding the properties file config by creating an instance of Properties class in the code. so the answer is this line:    sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("conf/quartz.properties");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oops, I found the problem, actually the code was overriding the properties file config by creating an instance of Properties class **in the code**. so the answer is this line:

`sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("conf/quartz.properties");`

Comment: Are you creating the scheduler using Scheduler sch = sf.getScheduler();?

Comment: @Steven actually it was for ages ago and I don't remember :D however as mentioned I found my mistake.

Answer (score 13):

For those who are using Spring + Quartz and `quartz.properties` file is not working (i.e. gets ignored while starting the application):

Quartz Scheduler (`org.quartz.Scheduler`) instantiated by Spring Factory Bean (`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`) won't read `quartz.properties` file from the classpath by default as it's said in Quartz docs - you need to set the reference manually:

[in case of Java config]:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    schedulerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
    // ...
}
```

[in case of XML config]:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
    // ...
</bean>
```

Comment: After adding setConfigLocation am getting `SchedulerPlugin class not specified for plugin 'jobInitializer'` error. Can you please tell me why

Answer (score 2):

If someone still looking for answer, they can use the below snippet

```
@Bean                                                                           
public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    scheduler.setTriggers(jobOneTrigger());
    scheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
    scheduler.setJobDetails(jobOneDetail());
    return scheduler;
}

@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the previous solutions dont work for you, then move your properties file inside the **/resource** directory of your project. Then your configuration will be picked up by default.